# What do 'rb' and 'wb' mean when opening a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, pickle, python-2.x

What are the implications of the binary vs default mode in Python 3?

When I try to open a pickle file that was saved in the other mode I get an error, while in Python 2.7 I could switch between modes without any issue. The problem can be easily fixed, but why does it matter in the first place?

In general:

- Which mode should be preferred for greater portability? Is there a specific scenario where a mode should be preferred (e.g. dealing with plaintext files, etc.)?
- What are the implications of the binary/default modes with respect to encoding such as UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#open):

> As mentioned in the [Overview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io-overview), Python distinguishes between binary and text I/O. Files opened in binary mode (including `'b'` in the *mode* argument) return contents as [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) objects without any decoding. In text mode (the default, or when `'t'` is included in the *mode* argument), the contents of the file are returned as [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str), the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified *encoding* if given.

Unsurprisingly, you should use the (default) text mode for text data, and binary mode for binary data – including `pickle` data, which is explicitly [defined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) as binary:

> The [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. *“Pickling”* is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and *“unpickling”* is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a [binary file](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-binary-file) or https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) is converted back into an object hierarchy.

Python 3 approaches the distinction between text and binary data [completely differently](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) to Python 2 – indeed, this was the primary reason for the change of major version number. As a result, it's sometimes the case that code which does not adequately consider the distinction appears to "just work" in Python 2 (but will then often bite you in unexpected ways further down the line).